# Qual a origem da gíria “mode”?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem, gíria, coloquialismos

Não tenho certeza se se escreve realmente dessa forma (mode), mas ao menos é como soa quando ouço alguém dizer.

1. ***Mode** quê?*
2. *Não fui **mode** a chuva.*
3. *Traga aqui **mode** eu ver!*

Na frase 1 a pessoa está dizendo o mesmo que “**por** quê?”, “**por causa de** quê?”;

Na frase 2 o mesmo que “Não fui **por causa da** chuva."

E na frase 3 o mesmo que “Traga aqui **para** eu ver.”

Qual é a origem disso, a etimologia? Suspeito que seja coisa do coloquialismo brasileiro.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é coloquialismo brasileiro. Outras grafias incluem "**modi**" e "**mó de**".

Mais que gíria, é parte do dialeto de certas regiões, especialmente do interior do país e do nordeste. Usos notáveis incluem as letras das músicas [*Pra Mode Chatear*](https://www.letras.mus.br/tom-jobim/86261/) ("Lá vem as criancinhas, que é pra mode chatear.") e [*Pelados Em Santos*](https://www.letras.mus.br/mamonas-assassinas/24140/) ("Minha Brasília amarela / Tá de portas abertas / Pra mode a gente se amar").

O Houaiss afirma que a palavra se trata de uma:

> aglutinação com alterações de *por amor de* > *promode/prumode* > *mode*

e o [Dicionário Informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/diferenca-entre/m%C3%B3%20de/para%20modo%20de/), considerando a grafia "mó de", que a expressão é uma

> Contração de "para modo de".

que, pessoalmente, me parece mais verossímil que a etimologia do Houaiss — e este também data a expressão "pra mode" como sendo de 1933, enquanto o [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) encontra exemplos anteriores, e.g., na peça *Fritzmac* (1889) de Aluísio de Azevedo e Artur Azevedo ([e-print](https://www.literaturabrasileira.ufsc.br/documentos/?id=140812)):

> ZÉ - Pois você não está contente com o Treze de Maio?...
> PRIMEIRO PRETO - É! Pru mode Treze de Maio preto já não vale nem dé tutão!

E no livro [*Dona Guidinha do Poço*](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/Dona_Guidinha_do_Po%C3%A7o) (1891) de Manuel de Oliveira Paiva:

> E apois não foi? Mode non corrê sangue. - Liquidou o sítio por pouco mais de um nada..

> Olhe lá! Foi tropa pro Poço, mó de pegar a mulher. Tinham passado diversas na estrada, diz que mó de ver a entrada dela na vila.

Comment: Interessante! Muito obrigado pelo resposta!